# How to get Screen coordinates from a 3D Point? Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I've seen alot of Screen-Coordinate to world coordinate posts, but have not seen the opposite. Is there an easy way of getting screen coordinates from a 3d point, from any angle I view it from? I'm using C++ and opengl

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection/866749#866749

Comment: @Mads Elvheim: Almost an exact duplicate. This question is specific to C++ and OpenGL. The other question is not. In fact, the other question is tagged "Java".

Answer (score 22):

erjot's answer is incomplete.

There are 2 additional things to take into account.

1. with `homogeneous = P . M . world`, the `homogeneous` vector is a 4-d vector in homogeneous space. In particular, to bring it back to the [-1:1]^3 cube, you need to divide its first 3 coordinates by `homogeneous.w`. `cube.x = homogeneous.x / homogeneous.w` (what some people call the projection divide).
2. You then need to transform the [-1:1]^3 cube to window coordinates by applying the Viewport transformation to it. `window.x = viewport.x + viewport.width * (cube.x+1)/2`

In case you care about the final Z, the transformation is not going through viewport, but DepthRange instead.

Answer (score 6):

Screen-coordinates for a vertex is just a result of multiplication such vertex by its projection and modelview matrix:

`screen_coordinates = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * world_coordinates`

You can do it by hand (especially if you're using some maths library for doing operations on matrices) or use gluProject, for example:

```
std::array<GLfloat, 16> projection;
std::array<GLfloat, 16> modelview;
std::array<GLfloat, 3>  screen_coords;

glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection.data());
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview.data());

gluProject(world_coords[0], world_coords[1], world_coords[2],
    modelview.data(), projection.data(),
    screen_coords.data(), screen_coords.data() + 1, screen_coords.data() + 2);
```

Comment: Downvote. gluProject does the right thing, but your explanation does not. Multiplying a point with just the modelview matrix and projection matrix gives you the clip space coordinate, but *before* the division by w. It does not give you the screen space coordinate. See bahbar's answer.

Comment: To judge whether it gives correct space coordinates or not you need more details about OP's world setup, e.g. I hardly ever use viewport settings for my 2D games. But it seems your crystal ball works flawlessly so thx for downvote :)

Comment: ps. isn't OpenGL's (fixed function pipeline) PROJECTION  matrix containg setup for the viewport? and what are the cases you need to explictly divide by w? GLSL is doing it by default.

Comment: you use Viewport, whether you know it or not. That's what makes sure you draw to your whole window (and typically something you change if your window changes size). gluProject takes 9 params, not 8. You removed the viewport one... And no, projection does not contain viewport transform. It brings primitives to the [-1:1] cube, as in my post. That's when _clipping_ happens. Before viewport transform. GLSL (I assume you meant the generated shaders?) is certainly not doing w-divide, since it needs to happen after clipping too (the clipper works on homogeneous coordinates).

Answer (score 2):

One another thing. Remember, gluProject gives coordinates where the beginning of coordinate system begins at the left bottom corner. Screen coordinates begin at the left top corner. To obtain proper values of screen coordinates value of y must be subtracted from height of the OpenGL device.

For example in Qt GLWidget to draw a text in (0,1,2) world coordinates it goes:

gluProject(0,1,2,modelMatrix,projMatrix,sc.x,sc.y,sc.z);
renderText(sc.x,height()-sc.y,"(0,1,2)");