# How to get rid of glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I am try to Limit OpenGL draw to part of the window. In order to do it I am trying to use GL_STENCIL_TEST option. Here is my code:

```
// Enable stencil and clear the stencil buffer
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

// Enable func and Op so drawing will effect the stencil buffer
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 0x0, 0x0);
glStencilOp(GL_INCR, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);

// Draw a rect to the stencil
DrawSolidRect(rectDrawArea);

// Enable func and Op so drawing will not effect the stencil buffer
// but will only effect places where the stencil was drawn to in the previous step.
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0x1, 0x1);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
```

The problem is that glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT) function is very time consuming, and since I am drawing with 25 fps, it really slows down the application.

I tried to remove this function - this solves the slowness problem but it causes flickering when I initialize the application - For about 10 seconds. Than it disappears and works ok.

Can someone suggest why the flickering is or what other function may I use that not so time-consuming?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rectangular clip regions, it's probably MUCH easier and faster to use glScissor. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml

As noted in the link above, also call glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST) to enable scissor testing.

Thanks to @datenwolf

Comment: The viewport doesn't clip. Drawing operations outside the viewport are undefined and things may be changed outside the viewport. You need an additional scissor (glScissor and glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'll edit my answer and add that info. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know about this, but I have problem with SCISSOR, since it works on Windows coordinates, which I do not have :)

Comment: Couldn't you perform a projection to get them?

Comment: See this post and @erjot's answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792481/how-to-get-screen-coordinates-from-a-3d-point-opengl