# Translate Java 3D coordinates to 2D screen coordinates

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm working with a Java 3D application called "Walrus" that is used to display directed graphs. The code already has a feature to highlight a node and draw label adjacent in graph given its screen coordinates.

Upon rotating the screen, the node is no more highlighted.

What I have is the node coordinates in 3D. I need to draw label to it.

Code for highlight using 3D coordinates

```
Point3d p = new Point3d();
m_graph.getNodeCoordinates(node, p);

PointArray array = new PointArray(1, PointArray.COORDINATES);
array.setCoordinate(0, p);
m_parameters.putModelTransform(gc);
gc.setAppearance(m_parameters.getPickAppearance());
```

1. How can I draw Label with 3D coordinates( Raster graphics throws error Renderer: Error creating immediate mode Canvas3D graphics context )
2. How can I convert 3D coordinates to 2D screen and use existing code to draw label at 2D screen point

Thanks,

Dakshina

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection, since once you figure that part out, drawing the label is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have an algorithm/method for converting `[x,y,z]` into `[x,y]` with the `depth` parameter:

The `x` value is : `(int) (x - (z / depth * x))`

The `y` value is : `(int) (y - (z / depth * y))`

Essentially, the depth is the focal point. The vanishing point will be at `[0,0,depth]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i used to convert my 3D coordinates into perspective 2D, x2 and y2 being the 2dimensional coordinates, xyz being the 3D coordinates.

use these formulas:

x2 = cos(30)*x - cos(30)*y

y2 = sin(30)*x + sin(30)*y + z

I picked the angle 30 as it is easy for perspective purposes, also used in Isometric grids for drawing 3D on 2D papers. As the z axe will be the vertical one, x and y are the ones at 60 degrees from it right and left. [Isometric Grid Picture.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328125659/http://mathforum.org/workshops/sum98/participants/sanders/isomgrid.gif)

I'm still working on rotation, but without altering the axes, just coordinate rotation in 3D.
Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.
This is the function to display Text3D at image 2D coordinates

```
public void drawLabel(GraphicsContext3D gc, double x, double y, int zOffset, String s) {
boolean frontBufferRenderingState = gc.getFrontBufferRendering();
gc.setBufferOverride(true);
gc.setFrontBufferRendering(true);
Point3d eye = getEye();
double labelZ = zOffset * LABEL_Z_OFFSET_SCALE
+ LABEL_Z_SCALE * eye.z + LABEL_Z_OFFSET;

double xOffset = LABEL_X_OFFSET * m_pixelToMeterScale;
double yOffset = LABEL_Y_OFFSET * m_pixelToMeterScale;
Point3d p = new Point3d(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, 0.0);
{

// Project given (x, y) coordinates to the plane z=labelZ.

// Convert from image-plate to eye coordinates.
p.x -= eye.x;
p.y -= eye.y;

double inversePerspectiveScale = 1.0 - labelZ / eye.z;
p.x *= inversePerspectiveScale;
p.y *= inversePerspectiveScale;

// Convert from eye to image-plate coordinates.
p.x += eye.x;
p.y += eye.y;

}

Transform3D scale = new Transform3D();
scale.set(LABEL_SCALE);

Vector3d t = new Vector3d(p.x, p.y, labelZ);
Transform3D translation = new Transform3D();
translation.set(t);
translation.mul(scale);

Transform3D transform = new Transform3D(m_imageToVworld);
transform.mul(translation);

gc.setModelTransform(transform);

//-----------------
int fontSize=(int)(10*m_magnification);

if(fontSize>20)
fontSize=20;
//---------------

// XXX: Courier may not be available on all systems.
Text2D text = new Text2D(s, new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
"Courier", fontSize, Font.BOLD);

gc.draw(text);

gc.flush(true);

// NOTE: Resetting the model transform here is very important.
// For some reason, not doing this causes the immediate
// following frame to render incorrectly (but subsequent
// frames will render correctly). In some ways, this
// makes sense, because most rendering code assumes that
// GraphicsContext3D has been set to some reasonable
// transform.
gc.setModelTransform(m_objectTransform);
gc.setFrontBufferRendering(frontBufferRenderingState);
}
```

This is the function to take 3D coordinates and convert them to image 2D coordinates and render using above function

```
private boolean displayOnScreenLabel(int node, String label) {
boolean success = false;
try {
Transform3D transform = m_parameters.getObjectToEyeTransform();
Point3d nodeC = new Point3d();

m_graph.getNodeCoordinates(node, nodeC);
transform.transform(nodeC);

Point3d eye = m_parameters.getEye();

double perspectiveScale = 1.0 / (1.0 - nodeC.z / eye.z);

double centerX = eye.x + nodeC.x * perspectiveScale;
double centerY = eye.y + nodeC.y * perspectiveScale;

GraphicsContext3D gc = m_canvas.getGraphicsContext3D();

m_parameters.drawLabel(gc, centerX, centerY, m_labelZOffsetCounter++, label);

success = true;
} catch (final java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(m_frame, "The 3D Graphics is unable to find enough memory on your system. Kill the application!", "Out Of Memory!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} catch (Exception e) {
success = false;
}
return success;
}
```