# Convert 3D world space coordinates to SVG viewport coordinates

Tags: javascript, math, svg, coordinate-transformation

I've been attempting to display the positions of players in a 3D game, on a web page, from an overhead view perspective (like a minimap). I'm simply superimposing markers (via SVG) on a 1024x1024 image of the game's level (an overhead view, taken from the game itself). I'm only concerned with the `x`, `y` coordinates, since I'm not using `z` in an overhead view.

The game's world has equal min/max coordinates for both `x` and `y`: `-4096` to `4096`. The `0, 0` coordinate is the center of the world.

To make things even more interesting, the initial position of a game level, within the game world, is arbitrary. So, for example, the upper-left world coordinate for the particular level I've been testing with is `-2440, 3383`.

My initial confusion comes from the fact that the `0,0` coordinate in a web page is the top-left, versus center in the world space.

**How do I correctly convert the 3D world space coordinates to properly display in a web page viewport of any dimension?**

Here's what I've tried (I've been attempting to use the viewbox attribute in svg to handle the upper left world coordinate offset)

```
scalePosition: function (targetWidth, targetHeight) {
    // in-game positions
    var gamePosition = this.get('pos');

    var MAX_X = 8192,
        MAX_Y = 8192;

    // Flip y
    gamePosition.y = -gamePosition.y;

    // Ensure game coordinates are only positive values
    // In game = -4096 < x|y < 4096 (0,0 = center)
    // Browser = 0 < x|y < 8192 (0,0 = top-left)
    gamePosition.x += 4096;
    gamePosition.y += 4096;


    // Target dimenions
    targetWidth = (targetWidth || 1024),
    targetHeight = (targetHeight || 1024);

    // Find scale between game dimensions and target dimensions
    var xScale = MAX_X / targetWidth,
        yScale = MAX_Y / targetHeight;

    // Convert in-game coords to target coords
    var targetX = gamePosition.x / xScale,
        targetY = gamePosition.y / yScale;

    return {
        x: targetX,
        y: targetY
    };
},
```

Comment: You need some kind of projection, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection

Comment: Is the [`viewBox` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) of SVG what you're looking for? `viewBox="-4096 -4096 8192 8192"` as an attribute to your `<svg>` element would move the origin to the center and provide the range of coordinates you require. If this is not what you want, then you'll have to be more specific, particularly on the relation between your script, the SVG and the HTML DOM.