# C# Filling a polygon in 3D

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

I want to use the C# **fillpolygon** to fill a complete cube in a 3D world. What I notice is that the **fillpolygon** function receives an array of points, but in my case, for each point I have (x, y, z). Is there anyway out I could try solve this limitations. Or is there any simple algorithm I could use to fill a cube or any object.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things is best achieved via some library OpenGL, DirectX - take a look at http://www.opentk.com/ or http://sharpdx.org/. If you insist you'll do it yourself, isometric projection is fairly easy to calculate, or take a look  on [How to convert a 3D point into 2D perspective projection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection)