# No operator "[]" matches these operands / no templated code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-keyword

Im trying to fix the example code in this question: [How to convert a 3D point into 2D perspective projection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection)

I've ironed out most of the mistakes, but one leaves me puzzled.

There's a class Matrix with an [] operator

```
float& operator[]( size_t index )
{
    if (index >= 16) {
        std::out_of_range e( "" );
        throw e;
    }
    return data[index];
}
```

and I get an non-matching-operator error on this code:

```
inline Vector operator*( const Vector& v, const Matrix& m )
{
    Vector dst;
    dst.x = v.x*m[0] + v.y*m[4] + v.z*m[8] + v.w*m[12];
    dst.y = v.x*m[1] + v.y*m[5] + v.z*m[9] + v.w*m[13];
    dst.z = v.x*m[2] + v.y*m[6] + v.z*m[10] + v.w*m[14];
    dst.w = v.x*m[3] + v.y*m[7] + v.z*m[11] + v.w*m[15];
    return dst;
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the operator definition.

Comment: change: `float& operator[]( size_t index )` -> `float operator[]( size_t index ) const` Note the change in the return types as well.

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely 30 seconds after formulating the problem, it encountered me that the `operator*` is receiving a *const* Matrix object.

Problem is here that `operator[]` is not a const function.

Leaving this here, because there were only two different Questions on google-

Comment: If anyone wants to formulate this in a better way, feel free to earn my accepted answer

Comment: See this post (it's the FAQ for operator overloading) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading  page down to __Array Subscripting__

Comment: Good link, but google does not rank it properly yet (or I made a mistake in my search terms).