# Converting points on a 3D plane to a 2D coordinate system w.r.t. camera

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates, coordinate-systems, plane

Please kindly redirect me if this is a repeated question:

Currently I have some points in 3D space projected on a plane, and I would like to convert it to 2D wrt the camera angle/view matrix I am currently at. For instance, the 3D coordinates on the YZ plane are (0,1,4) and (0,4,2), so the change in z is -2. However, I want to flatten this and achieve a change in z of 0. Any help or comments are appreciated!

[image: my professional illustration]

Comment: Often this is done with simple linear algebra. You have the axis, and so you know the "displacement" (in 2D) of X in direction of the specified axis. Do it for the 3 components, sum the displacement, and you get one common way to do 3D figures on screen.  If you are brave, you can take distance of camera, and calculate with trigonometry the angles of the camera point (than polar to rectangular coordinates). Or you put a plane in the camera and focus point behind (also just a trigonometry problem).  It is simple mathematics: just to drawings (and 3d models) to help visualize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a 3D point into 2D perspective projection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection)