# How to draw a cube with a coordinate system in Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 3d

I have a cube and there is a need to add a 3D coordinate system to it.

There is an example my coordinate system with a cube should approximtely look like:
[image]

Unfortunately, my progress seems so far from this example:
[image]

Maybe, I can find out how to draw X and Y axis, but I have no idea how to add the Z axis.
So, how to build the right coordinate sytem?

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cube extends JPanel {
    double[][] nodes = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1},
            {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}};

    int[][] edges = {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 2}, {2, 0}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6},
            {6, 4}, {0, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}};

    public Cube() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
        setBackground(Color.white);

        scale(50);
        rotateCube(Math.toRadians(60), Math.toRadians(10), Math.toRadians(0));
    }

    final void scale(double s) {
        for (double[] node : nodes) {
            node[0] *= s;
            node[1] *= s;
            node[2] *= s;
        }
    }

    final void rotateCube(double angleX, double angleY, double angleZ) {
        double sinX = sin(angleX);
        double cosX = cos(angleX);

        double sinY = sin(angleY);
        double cosY = cos(angleY);

        double sinZ = sin(angleZ);
        double cosZ = cos(angleZ);

        for (double[] node : nodes) {
            double x = node[0];
            double y = node[1];
            double z = node[2];

            node[0] = x * cosX - z * sinX;
            node[2] = z * cosX + x * sinX;

            z = node[2];

            node[1] = y * cosY - z * sinY;
            node[2] = y * sinY + z * cosY;

            x = node[0];
            y = node[1];

            node[0] = x * cosZ + y * sinZ;
            node[1] = y * cosZ - x * sinZ;
        }
    }

    void drawCube(Graphics2D g) {
        g.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int[] edge : edges) {
            double[] xy1 = nodes[edge[0]];
            double[] xy2 = nodes[edge[1]];
            g.drawLine((int) round(xy1[0]), (int) round(xy1[1]),
                    (int) round(xy2[0]), (int) round(xy2[1]));
        }

        for (double[] node : nodes)
            g.fillOval((int) round(node[0]) - 4, (int) round(node[1]) - 4, 8, 8);
    }

    void drawAxis(Graphics2D g) {
        int x_c = getWidth() / 2;
        int y_c = getHeight() / 2;

        // X - axis
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(round(x_c + 300), round(y_c), round(x_c), round(y_c));

        // Y- axis
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(round(x_c), round(y_c), round(x_c), round(y_c) + 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
        super.paintComponent(gg);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        drawAxis(g);
        drawCube(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setTitle("Rotating Cube");
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.add(new Cube(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: To convert x, y, z coordinates to drawing x, y coordinates, you need an observer point.  Draw imaginary lines from the observer point to the vertexes of the cube.  Where those lines intersect the drawing plane is where you draw your cube vertexes.

Comment: I recommend JOGL (Java Open Graphics Library) vs. Swing for doing what you are doing. Swing wasn't made for doing what you are doing, whereas OGL was :)

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724219/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-into-2d-perspective-projection